# How can I view hidden files?

Tags: pantheon-files

I know there are some files in my Home folder that start with a `.` (full stop).

How can I view them in Files? (I know I can use `ls -a` on the command line.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

or

right-click context menu

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to view them. This is a temporary setting sometimes, and you can press it again to hide them.

There is also a right click option, which has the same effect as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

If the setting isn't persistent, you can use this command:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences show-hiddenfiles true
```

and to hide again use this:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences show-hiddenfiles false
```

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes? :/

Comment: Ctrl+h now hide the window. I'm to looking for solution.

Comment: For the record, now that keyboard shortcuts are being shown in various places (including this menu) for accessibility, I've submitted a request to have the `Ctrl+H` keyboard shortcut shown in the context menu: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1751